# How do i get my check boxes to display and add numbers into a label on C#

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, label

Im trying to develop a form for an imaginary pet clinic in Visual Studio using C# and it consists of check boxes and a label. The checkboxes represent a service the clinic performs and when checked the price of the service is supposed to be displayed in the label, whenever any other boxes are checked theyre supposed to add to the price and when unchecked take away from the price. I am stuck on how i get the check boxes to have a value to display to the label

for example: the vaccinations checkbox (chkVaccinations) is supposed to cost 35 dollars

How do i get the check box to have a value of 35 and when checked to add to the label value which is zero?

```
private void chkVaccinations_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
    if (chkVaccinations.Checked) 
     {

     }
    else
    {

    }


    private void lblTotalprice_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: Who knows? Is this WinForms? WPF? UWP? ASP?

Comment: this is in Visual Studio using C#

Comment: Yes, and Visual Studio and C# can create all of the project types I mentioned above and they are all different. Got _any_ code to share at all/

Comment: private void chkVaccinations_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (chkVaccinations.Checked)
        }

Comment: Please Edit your question and add your code there!

Comment: I've added the code from your comment to the question. The reason nothing is happening is because you arent doing anything in your event handler other than checking if it is checked or not. You need to tell it to do what you want when checked, and what you want when unchecked too

Comment: @E.Mules to show a checkbox you have to use WinForms/ WPF/ASP or something else that has a UI... check what technology u are using in visual studio so we know how to help.  Please read basics about asking questions on stack overflow [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create Minimal, Complete and verfifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please read how to ask a good question on StackOverflow (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question accordingly if you want better help

Comment: Is it WPF ? If yes, do you want to do all the work in the codebehind or you want to implement MVVM pattern ?

Comment: Im asking, what code do I need to enter in the brackets to display ($35) in the label when the check box is checked 

if (chkVaccinations.Checked) 
     {
What do I enter in here to make ($35) appear in my label (lblTotalprice)?
     }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tbh your question lacks alot of information to be able to help you, but here is an idea of a solution following your example assuming this is codebehind. If you want a full MVVM solution I can update the answer for that.

EDIT: Made some changed to adapt the answer to your latest request in the comments

```
private double TotalPrice { get; set; }

private void ComputeTotalPrice(double increment)
{
    TotalPrice += increment;
}

private void chkVaccinations_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    if (chkVaccinations.Checked) 
    {
        ComputeTotalPrice(priceAssociatedWithThisCheckBox);
    }
    else
    {
        ComputeTotalPrice(-priceAssociatedWithThisCheckBox);
    }
    UpdateLabel();
}

private void UpdateLabel()
{
    If you want to show $ with 2 decimals
    string formattedPrice = string.Format("{0:0.00}", TotalPrice).Replace(".00","");
    lblTotalprice.Text= $"{formattedPrice}$";
}
```

Comment: I have changed my code to this one however "ComputeTotalPrice" in "private int ComputeTotalPrice(int increment)" has a red line under it as well as "content" in " lblTotalprice.Content = TotalPrice.ToString();" so i was just wondering how to fix those

Comment: I fixed the typo in my answer, ComputeTotalPrice was meant to be of type Void.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now if I wanted the price to be displayed as dollars $ in the label would I add a "(c)" somewhere? in the "UpdateLabel" section?

Comment: You can use string interpolation for that : lblTotalprice.Content = $"{TotalPrice.ToString()}$";  This is the same as doing lblTotalprice.Content = TotalPrice.ToString() + "$";

Comment: Okay and would that show to two decimal places as well? or do I have to add something else to represent two decimal places? Im sorry i should have included that in the previous question. I also had to change "lblTotalprice.Content" to "lblTotalPrice.Text" I am using a Windows Form App

Comment: I have updated my answer to fit your latest request. I simply formatted the price to show 2 decimals and change the signature from int to double. If all works, make sure to mark it as the answer please :)

Comment: It does display the ($) but it is behind the number, is there a way to get it in front of the number?

Comment: simply move the $ sign in front of the curly braces like this : lblTotalprice.Text= $"${formattedPrice}";

Comment: Thank you so much!! This Works! So one final question is I also have a clear button, how do I clear all the selected boxes when i press the clear button? Because ive cleared text boxes and labels using "txtTextbox1.Clear();" but when i try to type "chkVaccines.Clear();" the ".Clear" doesnt appear so how would I clear the check boxes?

Comment: @E.Mules `CheckBox.Checked = false`

Comment: Inisde the Onclick function of your button, simply cycle through all the checkbox and set them to false like @Adam Kinsley said